# Conditional probability integration

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Suppose I would like to compute the probability
$\hat{p} :=P(\max\{XY-1,0\} > 0, Y \in [3,5])$ where $X \sim U(-1,1)$ and $Y \sim U(-5,5)$ are independent.
To do this first, I considered
$$
\hat{p} = P(\max\{XY-1,0\} > 0 | Y \in [3, 5])P(Y\in [3,5])                                                   
$$
Note that $P(Y\in [3,5]) = 2/10 = 1/5$.
However, the resulting probability is a function of $Y$, not a number;
$$   
P(\max\{XY-1,0\} > 0 | Y \in [3, 5]) = P(X > 1/Y | Y \in [3, 5]) = (1-1/Y)\cdot \mathcal{I}_{[3,5]}(Y)
$$
where $\mathcal{I}_A(x)$ is an indicator function.
It seems that I can obtain the answer by integrating $Y$, i.e,
$$
\hat{p} = P(Y\in [3,5]) E_Y[P(\max\{XY-1,0\} > 0 | Y \in [3, 5])]
$$
which gives
$$
\hat{p} = \frac{1}{5}\int_{3}^5 (1-1/Y)\frac{dy}{10}.
$$

However this seems strange to me as the conditional probability should satisfy
$$
P(A\cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)
$$
without integration.
I know that the conditional expectation satisfies
$$
E_Y[E[XY|Y=y]] = E_Y[yE[X|Y=y]] = E[XY].
$$
and it seems that it is highly related to the answer for my question. 
However, I am sure how exactly these are related.

Any comments/suggestions/answers will be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your expression for $\hat p$ is precisely $\mathbb P(A\cap B) = \mathbb P(A\mid B)\mathbb P(B)$ where the event $A$ is $XY \gt 1$ i.e. $\max\{XY-1,0\} > 0$,  and the event $B$ is $Y\in [3,5]$.   You will not be able to avoid integrating the $\frac1y$ term when finding $\mathbb P(A\mid B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems all these conditioning/deconditioning/reconditioning steps only serve to muddy the waters for you.

To compute the probability of an event depending on $(X,Y)$, all that is needed is the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, and we have it, hence we can simply write $$p=P(XY>1,3\leqslant Y\leqslant 5)=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}\mathbf 1_{xy>1,3\leqslant y\leqslant5}\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dxdy$$ Using $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac1{20}\,\mathbf 1_{-1<x<1,-5<y<5}$$ this yields $$20p=\int_3^5\int_{1/y}^1dxdy=\int_3^5\left(1-\frac1y\right)dy=\left.(y-\log y)\right|_{y=3}^{y=5}$$ Thus, finally, $$p=\frac1{20}\left(2-\log\frac53\right)$$